# Why are $\Bbb S^4$ and $\Bbb S^2×\Bbb S^2$ not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am stuck in proving that $\mathbb{S}^4$ and $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$ are non-homeomorphic.

I have thought to compute the fundamental group of  $\mathbb{S}^4$ minus a point (which is trivial). But I am not able to compute  the fundamental group of  $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$  with a point removed.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I am not sure but I thin that $S^2 \times S^2$ minus a point should retract on $S^2 \vee S^2$ so you can't conclude anything this way.

Answer (score 5):

This is easy if one has the apparatus of homology theory to hand:
$H_2(X)$ is zero when $X=S^4$ but nonzero when $X=S^2\times S^2$.
An alternative is to use the second homotopy group $\pi_2$ instead.

I don't know of a proof that just involves the fundamental group.

Comment: I was thinking of a proof involving just the fundamental group. Thanks anyway.